# Leap Year C Programme

Tags: c

I want to write a C Code where user could give a 4 Digit Year number like :2018
The programm will say if its leap or not leap year. But i want to add another step.
Ex: if 2019 is not the leap year the programm shoudl tell me which year is next leap year.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   int year;
   printf("Enter a year: ");
   scanf("%d", &year);
   // leap year if perfectly visible by 400
   if (year % 400 == 0) {
      printf("%d is a leap year.", year);
   }
   // not a leap year if visible by 100
   // but not divisible by 400
   else if (year % 100 == 0) {
      printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
   }
   // leap year if not divisible by 100
   // but divisible by 4
   else if (year % 4 == 0) {
      printf("%d is a leap year.\n", year);
   }
   // all other years are not leap year
   else {
      printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
   }
   year+=1;
   printf("%d is the next leap year:\n", year);

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by creating a function which check if a specific year is a leap year or not. It should return a *boolean* result. Then you can pass any year you like to the function to check it. Like if the input was `2019` then you could add one and call it again with `2020` (or `2021`, or `2022` etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You should:

1. Extract the routine to judge if a year is a leap year as a function
2. Use loop to find the next leap year

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_leap_year(int year) {
   if (year % 400 == 0) {
      return 1;
   }
   else if (year % 100 == 0) {
      return 0;
   }
   else if (year % 4 == 0) {
      return 1;
   }
   else {
      return 0;
   }
}

int main() {
   int year;
   printf("Enter a year: ");
   scanf("%d", &year);
   if (is_leap_year(year)) {
      printf("%d is a leap year.", year);
   }
   else {
      printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
      // search for the next leap year
      while (!is_leap_year(year)) {
         year++;
      }
      printf("%d is the next leap year:\n", year);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Iam very new in Programming in which part of code should i use the loop?
Thanks in advance

Comment: it's a very bad idea to loop to find the next leap year. Just round to the next multiple of 4 and correct if necessary: `year = (year + 3) & ~3; if (year % 100 == 0) year += 4;`

Comment: @phuclv Looping may be bad but I disagree for being "very" bad because the loop will run only upto 7 times.

Comment: @MikeCAT but each loop needs many modulo operations which are expensive

Comment: A big Thank you to all of you i got it.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your conditionals to avoid duplicating the "is leap year" part. Once that's done it's relatively easy to find the next multiple of 4 and do the opposite checks to determine if it needs to be adjusted:

```
int main() {
    unsigned int year;
    printf("Enter a year: ");
    scanf("%u", &year);                          // WARNING: No error detection or handling!!!

    if(
       (year % 400 == 0) ||                      // leap year if divisible by 400, or
       ( (year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 4 == 0) )   // divisible by 4 but not divisible by 100
      )
    {
        printf("%d is a leap year.", year);
    } else {
        printf("%d is not a leap year.\n", year);
    }
    year = (year + 4) & ~3;                       // year = next highest multiple of 4
    if(
       (year % 100 == 0)  &&                      // Non-leap year if divisible by 100 and
       !(year % 400 == 0)                         // not divisible by 400
      )
    {
      year += 4;                                
    }
    printf("%d is the next leap year.\n", year);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this only works for recent years. Correct code that handles historical dates (before 1929?) is very hard to write because different countries/locales adopted leap years at different times (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar ).

Comment: Thank you so much you made it very clear to me.

Comment: @Brendan Just happened to notice a typo in your program. The code does not match the comments. `( (year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 4 == 0) )` should probably be `( (year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100 == 0) )` in line 8.